# TFS 2010 Build: How do I publish multiple test run results in the same build?

Tags: xaml, tfs, msbuild, mstest

All, I'm trying to split my MSTest test run into multiple runs because I'm getting OutOfMemoryExceptions thrown at about the 800/900-ish test mark. I tried profiling mstest.exe with SciTech's profiler to see if I could identify why we're holding onto so much memory, but no dice.

So, assuming I can't fix the OutOfMemoryExceptions, I'm going to try to work around the problem. The easiest sustainable path available to me is to split our test run into multiple test runs, one per assembly.

We are using the TFS 2010 default `BuildProcessTemplate.xaml` file as our build template. In it, the default behavior is to call the MSTest workflow Activity on all test assemblies at once. This behavior is ideal, except it won't work anymore due to the OutOfMemoryExceptions mentioned above.

I've split the test runs out out so that the build runs tests for each test assembly, then publishes results. Unfortunately, it appears that Visual Studio is expecting exactly one published test result.

So. Is there a way to combine test results into one combined test result that I can publish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Process tab of the build definition you can add as many test runs you like. When you select the Automated Tests row you can select the '...' button to open a dialog for adding multiple runs. We use this feature to apply different test settings on different tests.

Comment: Does anyone know if this was removed in later TFS versions? I don't see this functionality anymore. Wondering if someone has a work around for this now.